# How to get date from my Garmin ForeRunner 225 or Garmin Connect?

Tags: untagged

I just switched to a Garmin running watch (ForeRunner 225), and am missing some very basic stuff.

As far as I can see, Garmin Connect (online), only shows a pokey little map of my run (actual size):

[image]

I would expect to be able to a larger view map, hopefully full screen - am  I missing something? I am aware of [this](https://git.beroni.us/fullscreen-maps/garmin-connect/), but it does not work for me.

Last time I use a Garmin was over ten years ago when I had a ForeRunner 301 and they had a different app. IIRC, that had a map, it also had histograms below. You could click on either and it would show the other. Click on a point of your run on the map & it would show your data at that point, such as time heart rate, distance, etc. Click on some data, say a point with high heartrate, and it would show you it on the map.

I can't believe that they have regressed in their software capability, so maybe I am just too dumb to own a Garmin?

Can I use Garmin Connect to view data in the way described? Or is there a Windows app to get the data from the watch?

If not, which would surprise me, can I export the data, either from the web site or the watch? I am a programmer and can code my own app, if need be. I did find a way to export data for a run from the website as CSV, but that was only a summary - it did not show individual data readings for time/GPS/heartrate, etc.

I am probably overlooking something very basic, but I just can't find it & google is not my friend today.